# How do I publish a local github repo to Visual Studio Services?

Tags: visual-studio, github, azure-devops

I cloned a GitHub project called nopCommerce locally. I also branched the repo with the command

`git checkout -b mybranch`

I want to publish this branch **mybranch** to Visual Studio Services. How can I do that?

This is how my Team Services look like in the Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can publish a local github repo to VSTS by below steps:

1. Download [github extension](https://visualstudio.github.com/) for vs.
2. Restart vs and log in github in vs.
3. Clone github repo to a local path.
4. Replace origin with VSTS URL by **Team explorer** -> **setting** -> **repository setings** -> **remote** -> **edit** the origin URL as the git repo in VSTS, such as https://username.visualstudio.com/_git/projectname.
5. Create a new branch `mybranch` in vs, **branches** -> **new local branch from** -> **create branch**.
6. Right mybranch -> publish branch.
7. Now you can make some changes, commit&push, so the repo will be published to VSTS.

Comment: The above steps worked. It is required to create a project in the VSTS online with GitHub as the source control. In your steps, it is the **projectname** and that should exist before publishing.

Comment: If you "create a new repo" in VSTS you can use the Import button on the web to pull in code from GitHub

Comment: @Marina That worked for me too. One thing I noticed is that the remote repository URL for VSTS>Git project for me was https://accountname.visualstudio.com/ProjectName/_git/ProjectName that is different from what you mentioned in your answer above. Is it a typo or is there a reason behind the different URLs?

Answer (score 5):

If you already have a local Git repository on your disk, you do not really need nor the GitHub extension, nor creating a new branch.

You only need to :

1. get the URL of an empty Git repository on VSTS;
2. add a new remote with this URL;
3. push content to the new Git repository using the new remote;

**1) get the URL of an empty Git repository**

First retrieve the URL of an empty existing repository, or create a new empty repository using the VSTS web interface:

- From Code Hub, select **'+ Repository'** to create a new empty Git repository;
- Retrieve the HTTPS URL to that repository on the Files tab of the repository: it should be of the form

  `https://YOURACCOUNT.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/TEAMPROJECTNAME/_git/REPOSITORYNAME`

Onward this URL will be named with the placeholder 'URL_TO_REPO'.

**2) Add a remote to local repository**

You could add a new remote (called here 'vsts_origin') by means of Visual Studio, the command line, or a simple text editor:

- Visual Studio:

  - open the local repository inside the Team Explorer (it must be shown as bold in the Local Git Repository section);
  - Add a new remote by selecting *Repository Settings*, then selecting *Add* in the Remote section. Use 'vsts_origin' as the name, and URL_TO_REPO as the Fetch field.
- command line:

  - run this command to add a new remote called 'vsts_origin' to the local Git repository:

    `>git remote add vsts_origin URL_TO_REPO`
- text editor:

  - open the *.git/config* file with your preferred text editor;
  - add at the end of the file the definition of the new remote:

  ```
  [remote "vsts_origin"]
      url = URL_TO_REPO
      fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/vsts_origin/*
  ```

**3) Push your local repository *mybranch* content to the remote repository**

- push your code using the newly create remote by means of executing from command line:

  `>git checkout mybranch`

  `>git push -u vsts_origin mybranch`

  This will automatically create the remote branch called *mybranch* .

Comment: Will this push the entire commit history into VSTS, too?

Comment: Yes, all the history will be pushed.

Comment: Thx for the info. Did you know that you don't need to add a remote? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465863/how-to-import-a-git-repository-from-bonobo-git-server-into-visual-studio-team-se/50481486#50481486 (this worked for me)