# How to import a GIT repository from Bonobo GIT Server into Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: git, azure, tfs, azure-devops, bonobo

Since Visual Studio Team Services (on VisualStudio.com) is supporting Git repositories, we want to get rid of our own Git server (Bonobo Git) that is hosted on an azure machine.

Before we can shutdown the Bonobo Git server I need to import those repositories to VSTS.

Starting with the first repository it already fails:

[image: TFS Online error message when importing GIT repository]

- I tried to use the general .git URL. I could clone the repo on my local machine using this URL. I also tried the personal URL that includes my email, without success.
- I tried with and without authorization. Username are email and password of my admin user on the Bonobo Git server.
- Instead of importing to an existing repo, I also tried to import the repo as new repo.
- The source repo is not empty.

How can I make this import to work?

Comment: That's the username and password that you use when you run `git clone` on the command line?  Or do you use a personal access token of some sort?  It looks like Bonobo sets up a _username_ for your account in the administration page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue on my side.

If you want to import something from the Internet, you're going to need **Internet access**. So make sure VSTS can access the Bonobo Git server first. You can try connecting the Bonobo Git server through a proxy. Reference this similar thread : [Unable to import a git repository into TFS 2017.3](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/181777/unable-to-import-a-git-repository-into-tfs-20173.html)

And another workaround is [Manually import the git repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-git-repository?view=vsts#manually-import-a-repo) (works as expected on my side):

1. Create and cd to a temp folder, then run below command:

   `git clone --bare http://172.17.16.147/Bonobo.Git.Server/Test0523.git`

   `cd Test0523.git`
2. Create a target git repository in VSTS (e.g.
   `https://xx.visualstudio.com/GIT/_git/Git0523`)
3. Run below command to copy the source repo to the target repo. (*It will popup the dialog to let you enter the credential to access VSTS in this step.*)

   `git push --mirror https://xx.visualstudio.com/GIT/_git/Git0523`

   `cd ..`

   `rm -rf Test0523.git`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your Bonobo Git Server has a valid ssl certificate

Comment: You are right, we don't have a valid SSL certificate on the Bonobo Git server. This led me in the right direction. Thank you!