# Connect Azure Devops to an internal ip repository

Tags: git, azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have my Tfs/git Repository on premise over the ip 10.0.0.1:8080 and i want to connect the azure devops pipelines to that repository. I can not expose the git to the internet because the polycies of the company and they do not want to use Azure Repos.

I know that i have to make a service connection, but I can not reach the private ip.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Microsoft Hosted agent to connect to local git repos, then you have to expose the on premise Git to internet, otherwise Azure DevOps cannot connect to it.

However, you can try the following workarounds:

- Deploy a self-hosted (private) agent on any machine which located in
  the same network with the on premise Git server. Thus, the agent can
  access the on premise git repo during pipeline.
- Set up VPN/Proxy to expose the on premise Git to internet.
- Import the on premise Git repository to your Azure DevOps account, so
  you can use the imported Azure DevOps git repo instead of the on
  premise one. Since the on premise git is not exposed to internet, you
  may need to import that git repo manually. You can reference the
  answer in this thread for details :
  [How to import a GIT repository from Bonobo GIT Server into Visual Studio Team Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465863/how-to-import-a-git-repository-from-bonobo-git-server-into-visual-studio-team-se/50481486#50481486)

Comment: could you please provide references on how to deploy a self-hosted private agent? Thank you